# Merging two column name in an another one

Tags: r

I'm trying to merge to column name to create another one, 
Here is below, some data of what I'm trying to do. 
Thanks for the help

```
Bloc <- c("LE3", "LE5", "LE2", "LE5", "LE6")
Id <- c(69, 66, 71, 72, 76)
df1 <- data.frame(Bloc, Id)


Bloc <- c("LE3", "LE5", "LE2", "LE5", "LE6")
Id <- c(69, 66, 71, 72, 76)
Name <- c("LE3-69", "LE5-66", "LE2-71", "LE5-72", "LE6-76")
df2 <-  data.frame(Bloc, Id, Name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste` in `base R`

```
df1$Name <- paste(df1$Bloc, df1$Id, sep="-")
```

If there are many columns, we can also do

```
df1$Name <- do.call(paste, c(df1, sep="-"))
```

---

Or with `unite` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   unite(Name, Bloc, Id, sep="-", remove = FALSE)  %>%
   select(names(df1), Name)
#  Bloc Id   Name
#1  LE3 69 LE3-69
#2  LE5 66 LE5-66
#3  LE2 71 LE2-71
#4  LE5 72 LE5-72
#5  LE6 76 LE6-76
```